# How to connect the queue manager using CCDT file(2063 error) . adding the ChannelDefinitionDirectory in app.config file

Tags: c#, websphere, mq

Getting error code 2063 while initializing the

```
MqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManagerName, props);
```

App.config changes:

```
<section name="CHANNELS" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
 <CHANNELS>
    <add key="ChannelDefinitionDirectory" value="C:\filepath\path" />
    <add key="ChannelDefinitionFile" value="ccdtfile.ccdt.TAB" />
  </CHANNELS>
```

Code changes:

```
  Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
                props.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
                Console.WriteLine(_queueManagerName);
                MqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManagerName, props);
```

Comment: What version of MQ client are you using?

Comment: Hi Shashi i am using WebSphereMqClient 8.0.0.7

Comment: Looks like @jishan you modified the question with a different error code, it was 2058 earlier, now changed to 2063?

Comment: yes earlier i was not giving the right ccdt file name. that why the error was comming. I gave the right name after that the 2063 error code occur.

Comment: Does this help - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041320_.htm?

Comment: Hi.. i am new in using ibm mq . Can you please share the good resource either video lecture or book other then ibm knowledge center.

Comment: Did you read Shashi's answer?

Comment: yes. still i am not able to solve the error i am getting. I want to add one more thing the mq is installed in remote server. should i add properties like HOST in my code?

Comment: The reason you have a CCDT is that it contains the host, port, and other details the application needs to connect to the remote queue manager.   Can you edit the question and add the full app.config?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be related to the format of the app.config file. I used the following and was able to connect: Note that `configSections` must be first element under `configuration` section.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="CHANNELS" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>
  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <CHANNELS>
    <add key="ChannelDefinitionDirectory" value="C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\MFTQM\@ipcc" />
    <add key="ChannelDefinitionFile" value="AMQCLCHL.TAB" />
  </CHANNELS>

</configuration>
```